# Unable to access "DATA" in ubuntu after installed ubuntu alongside with window 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu alongside with Window 10 in my new Aspire E15 E5-573G-779S. The dual boot feature is ok. Only when in Ubuntu, I faced issue in accessing the "DATA" under "Devices", as shown in the massage below:
Unable to access “DATA”
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/kyeow/DATA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/kyeow/DATA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Appreciate if anyone can kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Is Windows still have its always on hibernation or fast start up on? That keeps all NTFS partitions hibernated including your NTFS data partitions. Turn off fast start up. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

OK thx Oldfred,I will try out later. But now I encountered even serious problem. That is, I have one incident under window 10, I merely did an action of uninstall and reinstall Mozilla Firefox browser via internet and reboot, but the dual boot feature is gone!! Why? Anyone have similar experience, please kindly help n share. Thx.

Comment: If I were to reinstall (using live usb) the ubuntu again (with the fast start-up off) alongside with Window 10, do I need to format the ubuntu partitiion first? If yes, may I know how to do that? If no, can I just repeat the reinstallation or I need to preset something first?? Thanks in advance and appreciate that.

Comment: I have solved the problems without reinstalling. That is, I have my dual boot back and able to access the "DATA" under "Devices". Solution is turn off the fast start-up in Window 10 and use boot repair in Ubuntu. Cheers.